# Tests referenced by Gradle are run multiple times

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit4, suite

When I am running a test using Gradle the test will run multiple times. Actually it is running the same amount of times as the number of suites covering that test.

So when running:

```
gradle test --tests com.mycompany.test.SomeTest
```

The test will run 3 times. see the following example:

```java
public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("SomeTest.test --");
    }
}


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({SomeTest.class})
public class SomeSuit1 {}


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({SomeTest.class})
public class SomeSuit2 {}
```

The output will be:

```
shay$ gradle test --tests com.mycompany.test.SomeTest 
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
:compileAspect UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestAspect
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
Done cleaning report folder [reports]

com.mycompany.test.SomeSuit1 > com.mycompany.test.SomeTest.test STANDARD_OUT
    SomeTest.test --

com.mycompany.test.SomeSuit2 > com.mycompany.test.SomeTest.test STANDARD_OUT
    SomeTest.test --

com.mycompany.test.SomeTest > test STANDARD_OUT
    SomeTest.test --

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 20.219 secs
```

How can I run this specific test only one time?

Comment: Try `gradle test --tests com.mycompany.test.SomeTest.test`. If it works, tell me and I make this an answer for you to accept. Btw. you should always and everytime use the Gradle wrapper for each and every project, even the tiniest one. ;-)

Comment: Could you please fix the title of your question and capitalization used in your question?

Comment: @Vampire "gradle test --tests com.mycompany.test.SomeTest.test." have the same effect

Comment: Then I guess it is not possible. You could open a thread in the Gradle forum about this to get feedback from the Gradle guys directly.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes i have done my best, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @Shay_t Doing your best is good enough, we'll take care of the rest.  :) Feel free to re-edit or even roll back your question in case I messed something up.